# Extensions of $C^k$ functions, analogous to extensions of smooth or continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, measure-theory, differential-geometry

Are the following statements true? **An answer with only "Yes" or "No" for each number is acceptable for me.**

16. Let $f: U \to \mathbb R$ be continuous with $U$ nonempty and open in $\mathbb R^n$. Then $\tilde{f} = f1_U+0 1_{U^c}$, the extension by zero of the function $f$, is not necessarily continuous. However, there exists  $\rho$, a bump function at a point $q \in U$, such that $\hat{f} = f\rho1_U+0 1_{U^c}$ is continuous and agrees with $f$ on some neighborhood $W$ of $q$ but not necessarily on the whole of $U$.

    - This is supposedly an analogue of (2) and (3) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3217143/clarification-on-extensions-of-continuous-functions-smooth-functions-and-smooth) for continuous in the case that $M=\mathbb R^n$
17. (Analogue of (2) and (3) for $C^k$, $M=\mathbb R^n$) Let $f: U \to \mathbb R$ be $C^k$ with $U$ nonempty and open in $\mathbb R^n$. Then $\tilde{f}$ is not necessarily $C^k$. However, there exists  $\rho$, a bump function at a point $q \in U$, such that $\hat{f} = f\rho1_U+0 1_{U^c}$ is $C^k$ and agrees with $f$ on some neighborhood $W$ of $q$ but not necessarily on the whole of $U$.

    - The $k=\infty$ case is (2) and (3) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3217143/clarification-on-extensions-of-continuous-functions-smooth-functions-and-smooth), and the $k=0$ case is (16). (17) asks about $0 < k < \infty$.

---

Context:

- [Verification on extensions of continuous functions, smooth functions and smooth forms.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249325/verification-on-extensions-of-continuous-functions-smooth-functions-and-smooth)
- [Extension of a compactly supported continuous $f$ on an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is continuous and compactly supported?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3217175/extension-of-a-compactly-supported-continuous-f-on-an-open-subset-of-mathbb)
- [Follow-up questions on extensions of continuous functions, smooth functions and smooth forms.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220794/follow-up-questions-on-extensions-of-continuous-functions-smooth-functions-and?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Didn't you mean 'but **not** necessarily on the whole U'? If so then product of $C^{k}$ with smooth function is at least $C^{k}$. To find correct bump take smooth approximation of $f$ and use fact that those are dense

Comment: @Radost Thanks! Are the statements wrong? I just changed $C^{\infty}$ to $C^0$ and to $C^k$, but I used the same argument, so I guess you mean that the arguments are wrong even if the extensions exist

Comment: Statements are true. Taking smooth indicator of some closed set contained within $U$ and containing $q$ the product is at least as smooth as the original function. Existence of such functions is discussed on wikipedia for example.

Comment: @Radost Thanks!