# Verification on extensions of continuous functions, smooth functions and smooth forms.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, proof-verification, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold.

**Please verify** the following **related** conjectures about smooth extensions.

In the books From Calculus to Cohomology by Ib Madsen and Jørgen Tornehave in particular [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207958/why-is-there-a-form-with-compact-support-on-a-connected-oriented-manifold-with-i) (see last sentence of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbI9v.png)) and An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3203182/a-compactly-supported-continuous-function-on-an-open-subset-of-mathbb-rn-is) (about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5UyH.png)), it seems we have the following

1. Let $f: U \to \mathbb R$ be continuous and compactly supported with $U$ nonempty and open in $\mathbb R^n$. Then $\tilde{f} = f1_U+0 1_{U^c}$, extension by zero of the function $f$ is continuous.

   - **I believe this is true** because I believe this is proven as part of Tu [Proposition 23.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kFg5.png) which goes: $\text{Assumptions} \implies \tilde{f} \ \text{continuous} \implies f \ \text{Riemann integrable}$.
2. Merged with (5)
3. Merged with (6)
4. (Analogue of (1) for smooth): Let $f: U \to \mathbb R$ be smooth and compactly supported with $U$ nonempty and open in $\mathbb R^n$. Then $\tilde{f}$ is smooth.

   - **I am not sure if this is true.** Tu doesn't seem to give a sufficient condition to for smoothness of $\tilde{f}$ when we don't assume $f$ is compactly supported, either in [Section 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn28E.png) or the rest of the book, but I think this is what Madsen and Tornehave claim in [Chapter 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbI9v.png).
5. Let $\omega \in \Omega^k{U}$ with $U$ nonempty and open in $M$. Then $\tilde{\omega} = \omega1_U+0 1_{U^c}$, extension by zero of the form $\omega$ is not necessarily smooth.

   - $\Omega^k{U}$ is the $\mathbb R$-vector space and $C^{\infty}(U)=\Omega^0(U)$-module of smooth k-forms on $U$.
   - **I believe this is true** because I believe this is explained in Tu [Section 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn28E.png) for $0$-forms.
6. Let $\omega \in \Omega^n{U}$ with $U$ nonempty and open in $M$. Then there exists $\rho$, a smooth bump function (defined below) at a point $q \in U$, such that $\hat{\omega} = \omega\rho1_U+0 1_{U^c}$ is smooth and agrees with $f$ on some neighborhood $W$ of $q$ in $U$ but not necessarily on the whole of $U$.

   - A bump function at a point $q \in U$ supported in $U$ is defined as a continuous nonnegative $\rho: M \to \mathbb R$ that is $1$ in some neighborhood $V$ of $q$ in $U$ with $\text{supp} \rho \subseteq U$ and exists by Tu [Exercise 13.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn28E.png), which I believe is applicable here.
   - **I believe this is true** because I believe this follows from Tu [Proposition 18.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKOGh.png), an extension from the rule for $0$-forms, Tu [Proposition 13.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn28E.png), to $k$-forms, but is not quite equivalent. Tu [Proposition 13.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn28E.png) and Tu [Proposition 18.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKOGh.png) are propositions about the existence of an $\hat{\omega}$ for a particular point in the domain of $f$. Here, I am making a conjecture without regard to a particular point: Since $U$ is nonempty, pick a point $q \in U$ and then apply Tu [Proposition 18.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKOGh.png).
7. (Analogue of (4) for top forms, i.e. n-forms): Let $\omega \in \Omega^n_c{U}$ with $U$ nonempty and open in $\mathbb R^n$. Then $\tilde{\omega} \in \Omega^n{U}$.

   - $\Omega^k_c{U}$ is the $\mathbb R$-vector space and $C^{\infty}(U)=\Omega^0(U)$-module of compactly supported smooth k-forms on $U$.
   - **I believe this is true** because I believe this I think this is what Madsen and Tornehave claim in [Chapter 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbI9v.png).
8. (1),(4) and (7) also hold if $U$ is instead empty, but the others above do not necessarily hold because the existence of a bump function assumes there is a point $q \in U$.

   - **I believe this is true** after some thought, but I have not found any references.

Comment: (4) is true because $f$ and $\overline f$ agree on $U$, and $f$ is assumed to be smooth. Outside $U$, $\overline f$ is clearly smooth since it is just constant.

Comment: @lEm Thanks! So it's the same argument as $f$ continuous and $\tilde f$ continuous in (1)?

Comment: Yes, as long as it is compactly supported. Actually the argument for differential forms is roughly the same, by working in a small open set.

Comment: So (1), (4) and (7) are pretty much the same for $U$ non empty?

Comment: Yes, indeed. They are fairly intuitive too. Afterall they are extension of smooth functions/forms, so you only need to check at the points on which discontinuity may happen, i.e. on the boundary $\partial U$, but they are constantly $0$ in a neighborhood of the boundary.

Comment: @lEm Thanks and what about (8) please?

Comment: It is not really that important to consider empty set. Because realistically we never need to extend a function/form defined on the empty set. But if you insist, note that there is a unique function on $\emptyset$, and it is vacuously continuous, smooth. Its extension is nothing but the zero function.

Comment: @lEm Okay so (1), (4) and (7) are vacuously true if $U$ becomes empty, but the others rely on the existence of bump functions which relies on non-empty $U$ and so the others are false for empty $U$?

Comment: No, you don't need bump function. Again, there is only one function and one k-form on empty set, they are vacuously smooth. The support is empty and so it is compact. In any case the extension $\tilde f=f1_U+01_{U^c}=0$, so it must be smooth.

Comment: @lEm I think I get it. The bump function arguments no longer hold, but you don't need bump functions as your comment demonstrates. Is this right?

Comment: Yes. ${}{} {} {} {} $

Comment: @lEm Thanks! You can answer if you want.